# How to persist CVPixelBuffer?

Tags: cvpixelbuffer

I need to extract frames from iOS front-facing camera, convert each of them to CVPixelBuffer and actually store CVPixelBuffer objects on a disk without loosing data.

Is there a way to achieve this?